# web component observer all attributes

Tags: javascript, web-component

The following code is the code I ran.

```js
static get observedAttributes() {
   return this.getAttributeNames();
}
```

The following code will show that the `this.getAttributeNames()` function does not exist. Is there any other way to specify an entire attribute of a web component as an observer?

*vanilla javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`observedAttributes` needs to return an array of attribute names;
names don't have to exist on the element yet.

```js
static get observedAttributes() {
   return ["foo","bar","baz", ... ];
}
```

You get an error because `observedAttributes` gets called **before** the 'this' Element is in the DOM
`observedAttributes` is defined as `static` so it'll be called off of the class, not an instance.

Thus you specify attribute names to be observed in JavaScript, not in HTML

Note you can not *add* observed attributes after static declaration in the class;
for that you need to implement your own *observer* with the `MutationObserver API`